# css table with first column fixed width has unexplained gap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

using bootstrap. 
reproduce [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zthzac5w/6/)

[image]

the first column is defined like this:

```
.feedback-table tbody tr td:first-child {
    width: 40px;
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

The html as you see in jsfiddle is sent the "bigger" html and wrpped inside a

Comment: You should provide us with your css class properties, but what I can guess is that you're setting `col-md-1` and `col-xs-1` on your first `<td>` element but also setting the fixed width which overrides those classes. Try removing your css `.feedback-table tbody tr td:first-child` and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović this maks the column wider. The design constraints are 40px wide.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović the css is presented in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gap in there is created by the ::before pseudo element of the .row class.

This is from boostrap:

```
.row:before, .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
```

Why do you need the .row class for ? Strip that and the gap will go. If you need the .row class, you could also just specify content: none; for the after and before elements

```
.feedback-row:before, .feedback-row:after {
content:none;
}
```

Later EDIT: I've seen your comment about constraints. To be able to specify widths with tables you need to specify the table-layout to be fixed. Therefore...

```
.feedback-table {
font-family: 'Arimo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 15px;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: right;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The table row spaces before and after. You can clear them using this:

```
.feedback-row:before {
  content: None;
}

.feedback-row:after {
  content: None;
}
```

Comment: @Visol, this maks the column wider. The design constraints are 40px wide.